# How structure variable is modified in formal argument

Tags: c, struct

In following program, when I passed a structure variable to decrements function how does actual parameters are affected as return void. I did similar other example and found that structure value is not changed when I pass it as formal parameter. How does this example is exception ..

```
/*P11.11 Program to understand how an array of structures is sent to a function*/
#include<stdio.h>
struct student
{
    char name[20];
    int rollno;
    int marks;
};
void display(struct student);
void dec_marks(struct student stuarr[], int a);
int main(void)
{
    int i,a=5;
    struct student stuarr[3]={
                                 {"Mary",12,98},
                                 {"John",11,97},
                                 {"Tom",13,89}
                               };
    dec_marks(stuarr,a);
    for(i=0; i<3; i++)
        display(stuarr[i]);

        printf("%d",a);
    return 0;
}
void dec_marks(struct student stuarr[], int a)
{
    int i;
    a=a+4;
    for(i=0; i<3; i++)
        stuarr[i].marks = stuarr[i].marks-10;
}
void display(struct student stu)
{
    printf("Name  - %s\t", stu.name);
    printf("Rollno  - %d\t", stu.rollno);
    printf("Marks  - %d\n", stu.marks);
}
```

Comment: You `dec_marks` function is being passed a pointer to an array of structures (or, more precisely, a pointer to a structure which is in an array of structures).  Your `display` function, on the other hand, is being passed a structure by value (which is probably not what you should be doing).  That should tell you all you need to know.

Answer (score 2):

This example is different, because it does not pass the structure to be modified, it passes an array of such structures:

```
void dec_marks(struct student stuarr[], int a)
//                            ^^^^^^^^
//                             Array
```

Arrays are passed as an address to their initial element, which amounts to passing a pointer; no `&` operator is needed. Integer variable `a`, on the other hand, is passed by value, so `a = a+4` assignment inside the function has no effect in the `main`.

If you restructure the program to take individual `struct`s and move the loop into `main`, the way it is done for `display(struct student stu)` calls then your program would stop working, as expected.

```
// This does not work
void dec_marks(struct student stu) {
    stu.marks -= 10;
}
...
for(i=0; i<3; i++)
    dec_marks(stuarr[i]);
```